# Correlating a Row with Column on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I currently have a table with a function that checks certain columns that have checkboxes, whenever they are "clicked off", to see if they're all completely empty.

The function does a loop from the first of the checked columns up until the last one that has to be checked. They go from 1 to 8, and their ids go from "f01_check" up until "f08_check". If all are empty, it adds a css class to its description column that changes background color.

The function looks like this:

```
function unChecked(rowNumber) {
    alert(rowNumber);
    var i = 1;
    var check = false;

    // Column loop
    while (i < 9 && check == false) {

        if (rowNumber.getElementById("f0" + i  + "_check").checked == false) {
            i++;
        } else {
            check = true;
        }

        // If all checkboxes are empty, add class
        if (i == 9 && check == false) {
            $s(description.addClass(emptyRecords));
        }
    }

}
```

The Dynamic Action leading to this function and its parameter is this:

```
var row = this.triggeringElement.closest('tr');
unChecked(row);
```

I realize that the `rowNumber.getElementById` doesn't work, but I can't figure out how to link or connect them. The way I'm looping through the columns might be a rough attempt, but it works. I've tested it on a set column and it it does stop whenever the loop reaches a checked checkbox. The problem is I just can't dynamically set the row to match the one that I've clicked.

I've tried getting the property `.rowIndex` as well, but I can't figure out where to use it, even if I do get the correct value.

Comment: `rowNumber.getElementById` does not work, because it doesn’t make much sense to begin with - IDs _must_ be unique within an HTML document. If your IDs are not unique, then that is the first problem you need to fix.

Comment: Try and get away from using IDs as the “panacea” of element selection. If those columns had a common class for example, you could easily use `rowNumber.getElementsByClassName`, and use a simple `for` loop to go over the result.

Comment: I had the problem of unique ids before yes. Since I'm creating the checkboxes that I'm verifying by using the `apex_item.checkbox`, I wanted it generated uniquely. Though whenever I try to use the API Parameter for its name, such as `'f01_#rownum#'`, I either get its string with the "#rownum#" statically written on it, or if I try something like `'f01_ ' || ' rownum'` I get an error that says it's not a group by select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a different solution, that also somewhat solves a different problem in the future.

Rather than use `rownum` to set a dynamic id for the columns, I changed it to it's primary key:

```
apex_item.checkbox (1, '1_' || pk, decode(data1,null,null,'CHECKED'), null, null, 'f01_' || pk) as lpb1
```

This basically helped me on knowing which row was being clicked, because the id also held it's primary key. This allowed me to use it's primary key value to improve the function. The `item_pk`is an item that gets its value from the corresponding table column:

```
function unChecked(row) { // var row = this.triggeringElement.closest('tr').rowIndex;
                          // unChecked(row);

  var i = 1;
  var check = false;

  while (i < 9 && check == false) {
      if (document.getElementById("f0" + i  + "_" + item_pk.value).checked == false)  {
          i++;
      } else {
          check = true;
      }
      if (i == 9 && check == false) {
          //addClass Segment
      }
  }
}
```

So if the report were to be filtered, the row number wouldn't match what the filter actually showed on the report table.

The previous solution was also fixed by removing the `case` clause from the select, as follows:

```
apex_item.checkbox (1, '1_' || a.pk, case when max(decode(data1,1,1,null)) is null then '' else 'CHECKED' end, null, null, 'f01_chk') as lpb1,
```

But again, the first solution showed actually foresees and handles a filtered report, so I believe it's a superior and more accurate solution.

Now I just need to complete the `addClass` segment. For some reason Apex is setting the field "static id" as the column header, which is slightly problematic since I meant to use the `document.getElementById`. But at least the main problem has been fixed. Thanks for the responses.